# How to open a CSS-only popup automatically on page load/using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created CSS-only popup which is working only by clicking on the link/button. I want to show this popup automatically on page load. Also, how this popup can be opened without clicking on the link/button i.e. By using Javascript/jQuery.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qbody1zo/1/)

```css
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: #339999;
}
.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
  background: #00d9ff;
}
```

```html
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

    <p style="color:white">This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us what you've tried (with jQuery)

Comment: You talk about your code actually triggering the pop up on click, may we see what you have written in JQuery so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are just hiding the popup using css opacity you can just use jquery on page load to show the popup or fade it in if you want to add a bit of animation.

Also its probably a good idea to set the display of the popup to none in css or you may run into problems at a later date. You could do something like:

```
.modalDialog {
  //added display none on element
  display:none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
  //opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  //Use jQuery to show the popup
  $('.modalDialog').show();
  //Alternativly use jQuery to fadeIn the popup
  $('.modalDialog').fadeIn()
})
```

Final updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/q4n7p0jx/1/

Comment: popup itself is not loading

Comment: why the popup is not closing on onclicking close

Answer (score 5):

There is no need of jQuery, you can accomplish this using Vanilla Javascript. 
To open the popup automatically on page load, set the hash to the `id` of popup.

**Demo**

```js
function openPopup() {
  window.location.hash = 'openModal';
}

window.onload = openPopup;
```

```css
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: #339999;
}
.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
  background: #00d9ff;
}
```

```html
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

    <p style="color:white">This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>

  </div>
</div>

<br />
<br />
<button onclick="openPopup()">Open popup by Javascript</button>
```

You can also create a generic function to open the popups:

```
function openPopup(popupId) {
    window.location.hash = popupId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to trigger click on the link when the page loads.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($('a[href="#openModal"]')[0]);
  $('a[href="#openModal"]')[0].click();
})
```

```css
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: #339999;
}
.close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover {
  background: #00d9ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div>
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>

    <p style="color:white">This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>

  </div>
</div>
```