# Automatic popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I am attaching this code which is a popup, opening when you click on the Open Popup button, but I need to make this PopUp automatic when the web page is opened. I don't know how to do this.

```js
var btnAbrirPopup = document.getElementById('btn-abrir-popup'),
    overlay = document.getElementById('overlay'),
    popup = document.getElementById('popup'),
    btnCerrarPopup = document.getElementById('btn-cerrar-popup');

btnAbrirPopup.addEventListener('click', function(){
    overlay.classList.add('active');
    popup.classList.add('active');
});

btnCerrarPopup.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    overlay.classList.remove('active');
    popup.classList.remove('active');
});
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.contenedor {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.contenedor article {
    line-height: 28px;
}

.contenedor article h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 50px 0;
}

.contenedor article p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.contenedor article .btn-abrir-popup {
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #5E7DE3;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s ease all;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.contenedor article .btn-abrir-popup:hover {
    background: rgba(94,125,227, .9);
}

/* ------------------------- */
/* POPUP */
/* ------------------------- */

.overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.overlay.active {
    visibility: visible;
}

.popup {
    background: #F8F8F8;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 600px;
    
    transition: .3s ease all;
    transform: scale(0.7);
    opacity: 0;
}

.popup .btn-cerrar-popup {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    transition: .3s ease all;
    color: #BBBBBB;
}

.popup .btn-cerrar-popup:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.popup h3 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.popup h4 {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.popup form .contenedor-inputs {
    opacity: 0;
}

.popup form .contenedor-inputs input {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 52px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 52px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
}

.popup form .btn-submit {
    padding: 0 20px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #5E7DE3;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s ease all;
}

.popup form .btn-submit:hover {
    background: rgba(94,125,227, .9);
}

/* ------------------------- */
/* ANIMACIONES */
/* ------------------------- */
.popup.active { transform: scale(1); opacity: 1; }
.popup.active h3 { animation: entradaTitulo .8s ease .5s forwards; }
.popup.active h4 { animation: entradaSubtitulo .8s ease .5s forwards; }
.popup.active .contenedor-inputs { animation: entradaInputs 1s linear 1s forwards; }

@keyframes entradaTitulo {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-25px);
    }

    to {
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes entradaSubtitulo {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(25px);
    }

    to {
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes entradaInputs {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,600|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Ventana Emergente Animada</title>
</head>
<body>

        <button id="btn-abrir-popup" class="btn-abrir-popup">Abrir Ventana Emergente</button>

        <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
            <div class="popup" id="popup">
                <a href="#" id="btn-cerrar-popup" class="btn-cerrar-popup"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                <h3>SUSCRIBETE</h3>
                <h4>y recibe un cupon de descuento.</h4>
                <form action="">
                    <div class="contenedor-inputs">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Correo">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn-submit" value="Suscribirse">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: very elegant method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222048/how-to-open-a-css-only-popup-automatically-on-page-load-using-javascript

Comment: See also "[Javascript/HTML/CSS popup](//stackoverflow.com/q/17610087/90527)", "[Open a CSS popup modal on a mouse move or a page load?](//stackoverflow.com/q/69498865/90527)", "[How to open a CSS-only popup automatically on page load/using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32222048/90527)", …

Answer (score 0):

you can use load **DOMContentLoaded** event

this event will be fired when the dom  is fully loaded.

or you can take advantage of the **load** event too.

see the below example.

```js
var btnAbrirPopup = document.getElementById('btn-abrir-popup'),
    overlay = document.getElementById('overlay'),
    popup = document.getElementById('popup'),
    btnCerrarPopup = document.getElementById('btn-cerrar-popup');

function showPopus(){
  overlay.classList.add('active');
    popup.classList.add('active');
}
btnAbrirPopup.addEventListener('click', function(){
    showPopus();
});


btnCerrarPopup.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    overlay.classList.remove('active');
    popup.classList.remove('active');
});

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
   showPopus();
});
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.contenedor {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.contenedor article {
    line-height: 28px;
}

.contenedor article h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 50px 0;
}

.contenedor article p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.contenedor article .btn-abrir-popup {
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #5E7DE3;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s ease all;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.contenedor article .btn-abrir-popup:hover {
    background: rgba(94,125,227, .9);
}

/* ------------------------- */
/* POPUP */
/* ------------------------- */

.overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.overlay.active {
    visibility: visible;
}

.popup {
    background: #F8F8F8;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 600px;
    
    transition: .3s ease all;
    transform: scale(0.7);
    opacity: 0;
}

.popup .btn-cerrar-popup {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    transition: .3s ease all;
    color: #BBBBBB;
}

.popup .btn-cerrar-popup:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.popup h3 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.popup h4 {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.popup form .contenedor-inputs {
    opacity: 0;
}

.popup form .contenedor-inputs input {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 52px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 52px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
}

.popup form .btn-submit {
    padding: 0 20px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #5E7DE3;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s ease all;
}

.popup form .btn-submit:hover {
    background: rgba(94,125,227, .9);
}

/* ------------------------- */
/* ANIMACIONES */
/* ------------------------- */
.popup.active { transform: scale(1); opacity: 1; }
.popup.active h3 { animation: entradaTitulo .8s ease .5s forwards; }
.popup.active h4 { animation: entradaSubtitulo .8s ease .5s forwards; }
.popup.active .contenedor-inputs { animation: entradaInputs 1s linear 1s forwards; }

@keyframes entradaTitulo {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-25px);
    }

    to {
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes entradaSubtitulo {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(25px);
    }

    to {
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes entradaInputs {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,600|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Ventana Emergente Animada</title>
</head>
<body>

        <button id="btn-abrir-popup" class="btn-abrir-popup">Abrir Ventana Emergente</button>

        <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
            <div class="popup" id="popup">
                <a href="#" id="btn-cerrar-popup" class="btn-cerrar-popup"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                <h3>SUSCRIBETE</h3>
                <h4>y recibe un cupon de descuento.</h4>
                <form action="">
                    <div class="contenedor-inputs">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Correo">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn-submit" value="Suscribirse">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why duplicate code?

Comment: yes you are right, i will change that duplicate code in to a function

Comment: Thank you all very much for the good response and the very little time that has elapsed.

Comment: And to close the popup by clicking anywhere on the web page, how can I do it?

Comment: you can attach a click event to `overlay` just like you did with `btnCerrarPopup`

Comment: eg:

function closePopup(){
                                    overlay.classList.remove('active');
                                    popup.classList.remove('active');
                                    }
overlay.onclick = closePopup;

Answer (score 0):

Use the `load` event over the `DOMContentLoaded` since we need the CSS and possibly backgrounds etc

Then just click the button

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() { btnAbrirPopup.click() })
```

```js
var btnAbrirPopup = document.getElementById('btn-abrir-popup'),
    overlay = document.getElementById('overlay'),
    popup = document.getElementById('popup'),
    btnCerrarPopup = document.getElementById('btn-cerrar-popup');

btnAbrirPopup.addEventListener('click', function(){
    overlay.classList.add('active');
    popup.classList.add('active');
});

btnCerrarPopup.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    overlay.classList.remove('active');
    popup.classList.remove('active');
});
window.addEventListener("load",function() { btnAbrirPopup.click() })
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.contenedor {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.contenedor article {
    line-height: 28px;
}

.contenedor article h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 50px 0;
}

.contenedor article p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.contenedor article .btn-abrir-popup {
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #5E7DE3;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s ease all;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.contenedor article .btn-abrir-popup:hover {
    background: rgba(94,125,227, .9);
}

/* ------------------------- */
/* POPUP */
/* ------------------------- */

.overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.overlay.active {
    visibility: visible;
}

.popup {
    background: #F8F8F8;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 600px;
    
    transition: .3s ease all;
    transform: scale(0.7);
    opacity: 0;
}

.popup .btn-cerrar-popup {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    transition: .3s ease all;
    color: #BBBBBB;
}

.popup .btn-cerrar-popup:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.popup h3 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.popup h4 {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.popup form .contenedor-inputs {
    opacity: 0;
}

.popup form .contenedor-inputs input {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 52px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 52px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
}

.popup form .btn-submit {
    padding: 0 20px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #5E7DE3;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s ease all;
}

.popup form .btn-submit:hover {
    background: rgba(94,125,227, .9);
}

/* ------------------------- */
/* ANIMACIONES */
/* ------------------------- */
.popup.active { transform: scale(1); opacity: 1; }
.popup.active h3 { animation: entradaTitulo .8s ease .5s forwards; }
.popup.active h4 { animation: entradaSubtitulo .8s ease .5s forwards; }
.popup.active .contenedor-inputs { animation: entradaInputs 1s linear 1s forwards; }

@keyframes entradaTitulo {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-25px);
    }

    to {
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes entradaSubtitulo {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(25px);
    }

    to {
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes entradaInputs {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,600|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Ventana Emergente Animada</title>
</head>
<body>

        <button id="btn-abrir-popup" class="btn-abrir-popup">Abrir Ventana Emergente</button>

        <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
            <div class="popup" id="popup">
                <a href="#" id="btn-cerrar-popup" class="btn-cerrar-popup"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                <h3>SUSCRIBETE</h3>
                <h4>y recibe un cupon de descuento.</h4>
                <form action="">
                    <div class="contenedor-inputs">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Correo">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn-submit" value="Suscribirse">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is this voted down? It is the most elegant of the answers here apart from the CSS answer using :target which is in another answer at SO

Answer (score 0):

any code in `js` without when button click will run first when screen loads,so remove when button clicked detector

```js
var btnAbrirPopup = document.getElementById('btn-abrir-popup'),
    overlay = document.getElementById('overlay'),
    popup = document.getElementById('popup'),
    btnCerrarPopup = document.getElementById('btn-cerrar-popup');

/*btnAbrirPopup.addEventListener('click', function(){*/
/*We have removed this click function and commented*/
    overlay.classList.add('active');
    popup.classList.add('active');
/*});*/

btnCerrarPopup.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    overlay.classList.remove('active');
    popup.classList.remove('active');
});
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
    background: #fff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.contenedor {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.contenedor article {
    line-height: 28px;
}

.contenedor article h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 50px 0;
}

.contenedor article p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.contenedor article .btn-abrir-popup {
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #5E7DE3;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s ease all;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.contenedor article .btn-abrir-popup:hover {
    background: rgba(94,125,227, .9);
}

/* ------------------------- */
/* POPUP */
/* ------------------------- */

.overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.overlay.active {
    visibility: visible;
}

.popup {
    background: #F8F8F8;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 600px;
    
    transition: .3s ease all;
    transform: scale(0.7);
    opacity: 0;
}

.popup .btn-cerrar-popup {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    transition: .3s ease all;
    color: #BBBBBB;
}

.popup .btn-cerrar-popup:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.popup h3 {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.popup h4 {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.popup form .contenedor-inputs {
    opacity: 0;
}

.popup form .contenedor-inputs input {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 52px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 52px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
}

.popup form .btn-submit {
    padding: 0 20px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: #5E7DE3;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s ease all;
}

.popup form .btn-submit:hover {
    background: rgba(94,125,227, .9);
}

/* ------------------------- */
/* ANIMACIONES */
/* ------------------------- */
.popup.active { transform: scale(1); opacity: 1; }
.popup.active h3 { animation: entradaTitulo .8s ease .5s forwards; }
.popup.active h4 { animation: entradaSubtitulo .8s ease .5s forwards; }
.popup.active .contenedor-inputs { animation: entradaInputs 1s linear 1s forwards; }

@keyframes entradaTitulo {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-25px);
    }

    to {
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes entradaSubtitulo {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(25px);
    }

    to {
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes entradaInputs {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,600|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
    <title>Ventana Emergente Animada</title>
</head>
<body>

        <button id="btn-abrir-popup" class="btn-abrir-popup">Abrir Ventana Emergente</button>

        <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
            <div class="popup" id="popup">
                <a href="#" id="btn-cerrar-popup" class="btn-cerrar-popup"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                <h3>SUSCRIBETE</h3>
                <h4>y recibe un cupon de descuento.</h4>
                <form action="">
                    <div class="contenedor-inputs">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Correo">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn-submit" value="Suscribirse">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```